# What is Colab uploading (repeatedly/persistently), and why?

Tags: tensorflow, firefox, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I am running a python-tensorflow-keras jupyter notebook on Colab, training a CNN on Caltech-256 images.   The data is loaded from the Caltech site directly to the Colab area with a wget, and never appears on my PC.   The notebook includes Tensorboard, and some Callbacks.  Obviously, as I first upload the notebook to Colab, that will use some internet bandwidth.   I would expect that the rest of the time there should be very little traffic - only enough to update my screen at the end of each epoch (every 600 seconds) or as I click on it.   However, there is actually quite a lot of traffic - enough to impact the other people in my house significantly.   I believe that the problem is with our upload speed (ie data going from my PC to Colab).  I am using Firefox web browser.  When I switch to Colab Playground mode, the issue disappears.

What is being uploaded, and why?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This isn't intentional; if you can repro this: (1) please `Help` -> `Send feedback` mentioning this SO question, and (2) try in an incognito window.

Comment: Hi Craig, I'm not sure what you mean by an incognito window, nor who to send feedback to.  I can certainly reproduce the problem, but I've also found an answer, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3196

Comment: Awesome, glad you got fixed up!

For posterity: from inside Colab, hit "Help" and then "Send Feedback" (which is the last option in the help menu). "Incognito" means "chrome Incognito window".

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks Craig

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3196

I don't totally understand it, but the workaround listed there works for me:

While the notebook is running, in the tensorboard display, click the settings cog (top right), and uncheck the auto-update box.    (You then need to click the refresh icon whenever you want to update your graphs.)

This has to be repeated every time you open the notebook, but it's a small price to pay for family harmony.